# JQuery MySql update

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

im trying to adapt this little snippet:

```
$("#checkbox_id").change(function(){
     /* CODE HERE */
 });
```

I have a series of checkboxes that are dynamically generated and their id's are always like "hug3443" were "hug" is the column in the DB and "3443" is the unique id for each row.

My objective would be that every time the checkbox changes state to update it own state in the DB.

Can it be accomplished with jQuery?

Thank you.

Comment: Assuming a web application with the database running on the server side, and the javascript at the client side, you will need some interface in between. What server side languages (PHP, Python, .NET, etc.) are available?

Comment: one thought on this method of working is that everytime someone ticks a checkbox it'll make a call to the server, which could cause problems if a lot are made at one, say if a user ran down the list clicking all the boxes in quick succession, which could cause the server to slow down or miss some calls. It may be better to submit a form with all the info at the end and make one call to the server updating the database. Kinda depends on how many checkboxes you have and how the site will be used

Answer (score 1):

I just found a script for this stuff and thought to post it here as I was checking this page a while ago until I finally came across to this script.  Tested it and worked like a charm and I have inserted it in my coding library.  Enjoy, folks.

http://www.jooria.com/Tutorials/ajax-20/jquery-live-checkbox-inputs-with-animation-effects-158/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use [live events](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn) to attach the change event handler to your checkboxes (so that dynamically added checkboxes will be handled also). Then simply do a AJAX request inside the event handler passing your script the new state and the name/id of the checkbox (you can then "parse" the id and column name in the script).

Comment: This method has the possibility of altering data on the DB?

Comment: Your PHP script must alter the DB. JavaScript by itself can not do that.

Answer (score 0):

Not without a server side script that would deal with the data changes.

jQuery is a client side javascript framework and doesn't have direct access to mysql, which is a server side daemon.

Have a look into pairing jQuery with php and mysql.

Comment: If so would this also launch an event if I deselect the checkbox?

Comment: If you attach an event on change, then it will be triggered on both actions (check / uncheck), it will be down to you to perform the required actions based on which event triggered your event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Code in javascript you write with the use of jQuery is executed on the client-side in a browser. A solution is from your script to make a call to a server page that will execute a MySQL update . For example like this.

```
$("#checkbox_id").change(function(){
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/page-that/makes/update.php",
      data: {param1:value1}
   });
});
```

Comment: From the PHP i know how to handle things, but getting it there is whats im having trouble with, from your example supposing the check box had the following attribute "name="CON1"" what exactly would be passing as $_POST to PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You should write some server-side code for managing database (php, ruby, whatever).
You should create something like API, which means, that server-side script needs to get some variables, which sended to it from clients (id's of rows, name and value of columns for example).

And after that you should write your jQuery frontend script, which will request server-side script for managing database tables. For requests you can use AJAX technology, something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://somesite.com/path/to/server/side/script',
    type : 'POST',
    success: function (data, textStatus) {
        alert('yahoo! we get some data from server!' + data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Im sorry to repeat my comment but my doubt is the exact same here: From the PHP i know how to handle things, but getting it there is whats im having trouble with, from your example supposing the check box had the following attribute "name="CON1"" what exactly would be passing as $_POST to PHP?

Comment: I just realized the last part of your code, sorry for the dumb question, im giving it a try. Thank you.

Comment: Im not sure the code is doing anything how can I actually whats is going on?

Comment: Hmm... Ok... I think that you can debug yours POST and GET array by using var_dump($_POST) or print_r($_POST) (print_r returns result in more human-readable format than var_dump), and of course you can use die('my break') instructions for debugging your server side script. Also you should stay alert('result is: ' + data) in jquery.ajax function - so you can see a data from server side script...
And, finally, read about debugging using Firebug extension for the Mozilla Firefox browser.
I wish that my information is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the id of the checkbox using javascript you can then split the name into the field name and id value. For this example I've added a - into id to give a seperator

(I think you may need to use the click event rather than change, think change may only work for drop down menus)

```
$("#checkbox_id").click(function(){

   var checkbox_id = $(this).attr("id");
   var id_bits = checkbox_id.split("-");
   // this would split hug-3443 into hug and 3443 setting id_bits[0] = hug and id_bits[1] = 3443

   $.post("update,php",
     {
       row: id_bits[0],
       id: id_bits[1]
     }
   );

});
```